# How Disable Gestures (swipe l/r) of CarouselPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use CarouselPage to have the right-to-left transition animation.
Could you please help me disable getsures in CarouselPage? I can't do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here?  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38553/how-disable-gestures-swipe-l-r-of-carouselpage

Comment: Yes. But CarouselPageRenderer dont have a ViewDidLoad method, and i can't find the getsures list for that would turn off them. 
CarouselPageRenderer does not have "View" property.

Answer (score 2):

Setting InputTransparent of the CarouselPage will do the thing:

```
public App ()
{
    MainPage = new CarouselPage{
        InputTransparent = true, //This!
        Children = {
            new ContentPage{
                Content = new Label{
                    Text = "Page 1",
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                }
            },
            new ContentPage{
                Content = new Label{
                    Text = "Page 2",
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I copied your code into new project and it does not work

Comment: It is odd, what is the part that is not working the swipe? I tested it before answering the question and it was working.

Comment: Property "InputTransparent " does not disable gestures (swipe) in CarouselPage.
Yes, it's weird. What is your version of the android?

Comment: ooh, I test this using iOS version, not android. The problem on android is that you have to set this property on every view inside the carousel page to make it work but I am not sure that is a good solution.