# Prevent users from swiping further than expected using CarouselPage Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am struggling to find a solution to this issue with CarouselPages:
[image]

Basically, users are able to swipe further than what I wish them to, and this shows a white page behind the current one being displayed. Everything works perfectly fine on Android, but not on iOS.

I have tried this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72031/is-there-a-way-to-disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-carouselpage but it completely disables the animation when changing. I still want the animation to be there, but not have the swipe enabled.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove all Pages but one as long as swiping should be disabled?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass : CarouselPage
    {

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

           foreach (var child in Children)
           {
                if (child != CurrentPage)
                Children.Remove(child);
           }
         }

         public void DisplayPage(ContentPage page)
         {
            Children.Clear();
            Children.Add(page);
         }
     }
}
```

> From: [Is there a way to disable swipe gesture when using Carouselpage](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72031/is-there-a-way-to-disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-carouselpage)

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72031/is-there-a-way-to-disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-carouselpage
I tried exactly that, but what happens is, it completely disables the swipe animation. I want the animation to still be there, but just not be able to swipe.

Comment: You use iOS or Android?

Comment: @Daniel Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252020/how-disable-gestures-swipe-l-r-of-carouselpage?rq=1

Comment: This disables all input on the entire page? I can't use the buttons and entry fields if I do this?

Comment: @Daniel Try this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33433/disable-carouselpage-finger-swipe

Comment: Can you maybe try it please?

Comment: @Daniel Well, at this moment I have to leave, but when I arrive, I will contact you to help you with your problem, are you in agreement?

Comment: Did you arrive?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, two days ago, I did not write you because the last time you did not answer and I thought you had solved your problem

Comment: Okay. Could you please share the code or your results with me? :)

Comment: @Daniel Before, can you show me the code of your page?

Post it in your question, so you can see what the error is, post the class of your page that has the error

Comment: Is there an error somewhere? Does it work fine normally for you?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it works normally for me.
And not only that, if they gave me upvote it's because my post is correct

Comment: I gave you an up-vote. Your post is not correct because it is firstly not "your" post. You simply copied someone else (as seen here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72031/is-there-a-way-to-disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-carouselpage). Secondly you did actually answer the question. I still want users to be able to swipe, but not far enough that they can see white... You answered how to disable swipe, which could have been easily accomplished another way.

Answer (score 1):

In response to @Héctor Manuel Martínez Durán's answer:

`Foreach` loop will throw exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` - to fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
{
    if (Children[i] != CurrentPage)
      Children.Remove(Children[i]);
}
```

Original:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

   foreach (var child in Children)
   {
        if (child != CurrentPage)
        Children.Remove(child);
   }
 }
```

Sample implementation:

```
public class MyPage : CarouselPage
{
    ContentPage ChildPage1 = new ContentPage();
    ContentPage ChildPage2 = new ContentPage();

    public MyPage()
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 30, 0, 0);
        Children.Add(ChildPage1);
        Children.Add(ChildPage2);
        CurrentPage = ChildPage1;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Children[i] != CurrentPage)
                Children.Remove(Children[i]);
        }
    }

    public void DisplayPage(ContentPage page)
    {
        Children.Clear();
        Children.Add(page);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Attempted to submit as an edit, results below
Jo*** review: Reject
This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
Ho*** review: Reject
This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ContentPage> pageList;
public MainPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();            
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    pageList = Children.ToList();
    foreach (var child in Children.ToList())
    {
        if (child != CurrentPage)
        {
            Children.Remove(child);
        }                    
    }
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Children.Add(pageList[1]);
    CurrentPage = Children[1];
    Children.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this self-contained custom solution. Single code file and simple usage.

Article here: https://www.roccacreative.co.uk/fyi/xamarin-forms-manual-carousel

Code: https://github.com/roccacreative/XamarinForms-Carousel

Comment: For the downvoters, where is your solution and what is wrong with this one?